# C# cannot save file from url with proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, download, webclient, webresponse

I'm trying to download a file from a url. I try two approachs but it isn't working with external files.

I think it's happening because I have internet over proxy. I can download internal network files (images, mp3, mp4, whatever...) but when I try to download something in external network it gives me *timeout* or *404 Not Found*.

**1st approach:** *System.Net.WebResponse, System.IO.FileStream*

```
     try
        {
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential("myNetworkUserName", "myNetworkPassword", "myNetworkDomain");
            var proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy(); //new WebProxy("myNetworkProxy") <-- I TRY BOOTH WAYS
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://farm1.static.flickr.com/83/263570357_e1b9792c7a.jpg"); //External image link

            proxy.Credentials = credentials;

            request.Proxy = proxy;

            responseExternalImage = request.GetResponse();//explode here ex=""Unable to connect to the remote server""

            string fileName = GetFileName(response.ResponseUri.OriginalString);
                Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
                {
                    content = br.ReadBytes(50000000);//perto de 50Mb
                    br.Close();
                }
                response.Close();

                FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathToSaveFile + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);
                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
                try
                {
                    bw.Write(content);
                }
                finally
                {
                    fs.Close();
                    bw.Close();
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

The exception caught at **GetResponse()** says: "Unable to connect to the remote server", ""A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 77.238.160.184:80""

---

**2nd approach:** *System.Net.WebClient, DownloadFile*

```
      try
        {
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential("xpta264", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Xpta264Password"], "ptsi");
            var proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
            proxy.Credentials = credentials;

            // Create a new WebClient instance.
            using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
            {
                myWebClient.Proxy = proxy;
                // Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
                myWebClient.DownloadFile("http://farm1.static.flickr.com/83/263570357_e1b9792c7a.jpg", pathToSaveFile + "\\testImage.jpg");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```

The exception was caught at **DownloadFile** method and gives me the same error.

Hope someone can help me.

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy()` is obsolete and doesn't handle all cases.  From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.getdefaultproxy.aspx):

> **Note: This API is now obsolete.**
>
> The GetDefaultProxy method does not pick up any dynamic settings that
>   are generated from scripts run by Internet Explorer, from automatic
>   configuration entries, or from DHCP or DNS lookups.
>
> Applications should use the WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy property and
>   the WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy method instead of the GetDefaultProxy
>   method.

A better approach is to try to request a url and see if a proxy was used.  I use this code in my own production system and it seems to work pretty well.  Once you find the proxy, you can cache the address somewhere:

```
WebProxy proxy = null;

Uri testUri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/"); // replace with REAL url
Uri proxyEndpoint = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy().GetProxy(testUri);
if (!testUri.Equals(proxyEndpoint))
    proxy = new WebProxy(proxyEndPoint.ToString());
```

You can also just try calling `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()` and see if that gives you the proxy, but I remember having problems with that which is why I went the request route above.  YMMV.

Comment: I think I don't understand...What is the url to replace for your "http://www.example.com/"? The proxy url or the url of the file I try to download?
In boot ways the 'proxy' variable never was fill... =(

Comment: proxyEndpoint value is exactly the same than testUri... =/ this means that my proxy is not found, correct?

Comment: Sounds like your proxy is not being found.  You might have to set it up manually before each WebRequest.  Does a web browser work on this machine, i.e., does it detect proxy settings properly?

Comment: Yes, everything is working on web browsers (IE, Firefox and Chrome...) I set up proxy manually doing
`var proxy = new WebProxy("myProxyAddress from InternetOptions");`
but gives me "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." exception at GetResponse =(

Comment: Weird.. Are you sure the remote address actually exists?

Comment: Apparently my problem is even more stranger. I cannot ping any website out of my network. I try in a collegue's computer and the code works without any proxy. I already put this question to my company's helpdesk. =/

Comment: **For the record**: I was using "Check Point Endpoint Connect", a VPN application to connect to network. I use it with a standalone application but the same application is available through browser. The standalone application block me internet connection in many ways. When I change to remote acess application in browser everything works perfectly without using any proxy. Thanks for all replys anyway.